# RoR app Crashed after page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is Something really weird with my RoR application
Everything goes fine when i start the server and run the application on the local, as soon as i refresh the page i get an error

here is the log:

```
Processing ActionController::Base#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-06 23:45:26) [GET]

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4

app/controllers/home_controller.rb:1
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
devise (1.0.10) lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb:43:in `call'
Rendered rescues/_trace (66.0ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (0.0ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

I recently installed the gem devise, everything seem to have been working fine until i started working on another page of the same website. Now the problem is that whenever i invoke the new page im working on and refresh it, the page crashes with the above trace.
I have no clue where im going wrong! :( Can anyone pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide your controller (and other relevant) code, better answers can be provided, but...

Errors that happen after a refresh are usually session or cookie related. If your storing sessions in the cookie (default in rails), this is very likely to be the case.

Also, you'll want to look at line 4 of application_controller.rb:

> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4

Comment: Thanks for the super fast answer